# String formatting [str.format()] with a dictionary key which is a str() of a number

Tags: python-2.7, python

Python neophyte here. I was wondering if someone could help with the `KeyError` I am getting when using a dictionary for string interpolation in [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

```
dictionary = {'key1': 'val1', '1': 'val2'}

string1 = 'Interpolating {0[key1]}'.format(dictionary)
print string1
```

The above works fine and yields:

```
Interpolating val1
```

However doing the following:

```
dictionary = {'key1': 'val1', '1': 'val2'}

string2 = 'Interpolating {0[1]}'.format(dictionary)
print string2
```

results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    string2 = 'Interpolating {0[1]}'.format(dictionary)
KeyError: 1L
```

<del>So the problem seems to be in the interpretation of the numeric key as a list index, IMHO.</del> Is there any way to work around this? <del>(i.e. convey that this is instead a dictionary key)</del>

TIA and apologies if this question has been asked before(couldn't find anything relevant with my search-fu).

Edit 1: The key is not numeric as was erroneously noted, earlier. Instead it is a string representation of a number - as was pointed out by [BrenBarn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11130837/391113).

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to do it as `string2 = 'Interpolating {}'.format(dictionary['1'])` ?

Comment: The usual way to use format would be `'Interpolating {key1}'.format(**dictionary)`

Comment: kobejohn: In the context I am using this interpolation it is expedient to do it as discussed in the question. Since I am then using this to access an attribute(i.e. something like `'{0[1].some_attr}'.format({'1' : someobj})`

Comment: Just to make sure things are clear, as BrenBarn noted your example does not use a numeric key. It uses the string `'1'` as the key. You'll have to change your dict to {1: someobj}.

Comment: kobejohn: True. I have updated the question/description. Still soliciting workarounds for the string-representation-of-numbers-as-keys-in-interpolation-dictionaries problem(if any).

Comment: I don't see any remaining issues. Strings as keys the way you want to use them: doesn't work. Numbers the way you want to use them: works. Is there anything else to be answered?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No.  According to [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings):

> Because arg_name is not quote-delimited, it is not possible to specify arbitrary dictionary keys (e.g., the strings '10' or ':-]') within a format string.

So you can't use strings consisting of numbers as dictionary keys in format strings.

Note that your key isn't numeric, and it's not trying to use it as a list index.  Your key is a string that happens to contain a digit character.  What it's trying to do is use the number 1 (not the string "1") as a dictionary key.  It will work if you use the number 1 as your dictionary key (i.e., make your dict `{'key1': 'val1', 1: 'val2'}`).

Comment: I had read this bit of the docs and the [PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) before posting. However I was wondering if the Python gurus had any tips/suggestions/workarounds. Guess not. Also, you are right - the key is a string and not numeric. Duh!

Answer (score 9):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
dictionary = {'key1': 'val1', '1': 'val2'}
string2 = 'Interpolating {key1}'.format(**dictionary)
print string2
```

Comment: Simple and most effective answer at least for the more general question of using a dict to supply values for a format command [+1]

Answer (score -1):

You're right - the parser isn't that complex, and can't handle variable subscripts for dictionaries. Your work around is:

```
string2 = 'Interpolating {somevar}'.format(whateverhere..., somevar=dictionary['1'])
```

Answer (score -1):

If your dictionary keys are strings, a possible workaround is to convert your dictionary to a class:

```
class ClassFromDict:
    def __init__ (self, dct) :
        for key in dct.keys():
            self.__dict__[key] = dct[key]

dictionary = {'key1': 'val1', '1': 'val2'}
classfromdict = ClassFromDict(dictionary)

string1 = 'Interpolating {0.key1}'.format(classfromdict)
print string1
string2 = 'Interpolating {0.1}'.format(classfromdict)
print string2
```