# python string format() with dict with integer keys

Tags: python, string, templates, dictionary, format

I would like to use Python string's `format()` to act as a quick and dirty template. However, the `dict` that I would like to use has keys which are (string representations) of integers. a simplified example follows:

```
s = 'hello there {5}'
d = {'5': 'you'}
s.format(**d)
```

the above code throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

is it possible to do the above?

Comment: Just a note, don't use `str` as a variable name as it will override the builtin `str` class.

Comment: `{[5]}` would work if the key was actually an integer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

We've established that it won't work, but how about a solution:

Although `str.format` won't work in this case, funnily enough the old `%` formatting will. This is not recommended, but you did ask for a *quick and dirty template*.

```
>>> 'hello there %(5)s' % {'5': 'you'}
'hello there you'
```

Do note though that this won't work for integer keys.

```
>>> 'hello there %(5)s' % {5: 'you'}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    'hello there %(5)s' % {5: 'you'}
KeyError: '5'
```

Answer (score 8):

I love the idea of extending the Formatter so that it allows arbitrary field names (integers, field names with a colon etc). An implementation might look like this:

```
import string, re

class QuFormatter(string.Formatter):
    def _quote(self, m):
        if not hasattr(self, 'quoted'):
            self.quoted = {}
        key = '__q__' + str(len(self.quoted))
        self.quoted[key] = m.group(2)
        return '{' + m.group(1) + key + m.group(3) + '}'

    def parse(self, format_string):
        return string.Formatter.parse(self,
            re.sub(r'{([^}`]*)`([^}`]*)`([^}]*)}', self._quote, format_string))

    def get_value(self, key, args, kwargs):
        if key.startswith('__q__'):
            key = self.quoted[key]
        return string.Formatter.get_value(self, key, args, kwargs)
```

Usage:

```
d = {'5': 'you', '6': 'me', "okay":1, "weird:thing!": 123456}
print QuFormatter().format(
     'hello there {`5`} {`6`:20s}--{okay}--{`weird:thing!`:20,d}', 
     **d)
```

So fields in backticks are treated literally.

Answer (score 7):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130790/string-formatting-str-format-with-a-dictionary-key-which-is-a-str-of-a-num) for answers to your problems. It seems that you cannot use strings consisting of numbers as dictionary keys in format strings ([docs link](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings)).

If you can use a key other than 5 then it will work:

```
my_string='hello there {spam:s}'
d={'spam': 'you'}
print my_string.format(**d) # Returns "hello there you"
```

Comment: The most important part of the linked answer is the quote from the docs: `Because arg_name is not quote-delimited, it is not possible to specify arbitrary dictionary keys (e.g., the strings '10' or ':-]') within a format string.`

Answer (score 3):

From **PEP 3101**

> The built-in string class (and also the unicode class in 2.6) will
>       gain a new method, 'format', which takes an arbitrary number of
>       positional and keyword arguments:

```
"The story of {0}, {1}, and {c}".format(a, b, c=d)
```

> Within a format string, each positional argument is identified
>       with a number, starting from zero, so in the above example, 'a' is
>       argument 0 and 'b' is argument 1.  Each keyword argument is
>       identified by its keyword name, so in the above example, 'c' is
>       used to refer to the third argument.

Numeric values used in `str.format` are positional arguments. So you can not do that.

You can reach PEP 3101 from [here](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/). Related section is  is under *String Methods*

As @Volatility mentioned, you can use `%` formatter for this.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something with `get_value` in a custom `string.Formatter` to try replacement fields as dictionary keys before falling back on index into arg keys - note the possible conflict of priority and intent here... so it's not exactly recommended, but an idea of what's possible:

```
import string

class MyFormatter(string.Formatter):
    def get_value(self, key, args, kwargs):
        try:
            return kwargs[str(key)]
        except KeyError:
            return super(MyFormatter, self).get_value(key, args, kwargs)

s = 'hello there {5} - you are number {0}'
d = {'5': 'you'}
print MyFormatter().format(s, 1, 2, 3, **d)
# hello there you - you are number 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible, using the fact `{k}` seeks for the `(k+1)`th positional argument.

```
def populate_list(d):
   """ Return a list l verifying l[k] = d[str(k)] for each natural k """
   return [d.get(str(k)) for k in range(1 + max(map(int, d)))] if d else []

def format_with_int_keys(s,d):
   """ Replace each {k} in s by d[str(k)] """
   return s.format(*populate_list(d))

s = 'hello there {5}'
d = {'5': 'you'}
print (format_with_int_keys(s,d))
```

**Edit**: It's actually a detailed version of @wim solution.