# How to replace parenthesis and text within it in Python string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have two strings like this.

```
string1 = "Today I went to the (market) to pick up some (fruit)."
string2 = "Today I went to (school) to learn (algebra) and science."
```

I want to remove and replace the parenthesis and the text within the parenthesis in both strings based on the following dictionary.

```
word_dict = {'market': 'library', 'fruit': 'books', 'school': 'class', 'algebra': 'calculus'};
```

I want the new strings to be:

```
string1 = "Today I went to the library to pick up some books."
string2 = "Today I went to class to learn calculus and science."
```

In order to do this I need to capture the text within the parenthesis so that I can use that as a key to get the value in the dictionary. Then I need to replace the parenthesis and the text with that value. I'm having trouble with the regex and how to go about doing this.

Comment: Take a look at this, the use of dictionary may do the job:<br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677660/python-string-format-with-dict-with-integer-keys

Comment: Where do the original strings come from? Is it possible to have all the `(word)`s replaced with `{word}`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace):

```
string1 = "Today I went to the (market) to pick up some (fruit)."
string2 = "Today I went to (school) to learn (algebra) and science."
word_dict = {'market': 'library', 'fruit': 'books', 'school': 'class', 'algebra': 'calculus'}

for word, translation in word_dict.items():  # Use word_dict.iteritems() for Python 2
    string1 = string1.replace('(' + word + ')', translation)
    string2 = string2.replace('(' + word + ')', translation)
```

---

You could also use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format) if you can control the initial strings to use `{}` instead of `()`:

```
string1 = "Today I went to the {market} to pick up some {fruit}."
string2 = "Today I went to {school} to learn {algebra} and science."
word_dict = {'market': 'library', 'fruit': 'books', 'school': 'class', 'algebra': 'calculus'}

string1 = string1.format(**word_dict)
string2 = string2.format(**word_dict)
```

If you can't control the initial output, but would like to use `str.format()` anyways, you can replace any occurrences of `(` and `)` with `{` and `}`:

```
string1 = string1.replace('(', '{').replace(')', '}').format(**word_dict)
string2 = string2.replace('(', '{').replace(')', '}').format(**word_dict)
```

Or to do the same in a much cleaner way, you can use [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) along with [`str.maketrans()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans):

```
trd = str.maketrans('()', '{}')
string1 = string1.translate(trd).format(**word_dict)
string2 = string2.translate(trd).format(**word_dict)
```

Keep in mind that this will replace any parenthesis with curly brackets even if they're not surrounding a word you want to replace. You could reverse translate the remaining curly brackets using `rev_trd = str.maketrans('{}', '()')` after you've formatted the string; but usually at that point you're better off just using the `for` loop and `str.replace()` as shown in the first code section. Unless you can change the initial strings to just contain curly brackets, then use that.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `dict.items()`

```
>>> string1 = "Today I went to the (market) to pick up some (fruit)."
>>> string2 = "Today I went to (school) to learn (algebra) and science."
>>> word_dict = {'market': 'library', 'fruit': 'books', 'school': 'class', 'algebra': 'calculus'}
>>> for i,j in word_dict.items():
    string1 = string1.replace('(' + i + ')', j)
    string2 = string2.replace('(' + i + ')', j)


>>> string1
'Today I went to the library to pick up some books.'
>>> string2
'Today I went to class to learn calculus and science.'
```

Comment: I feel like this should be a comment to my answer. He asked how to replace stuff in strings and your answer is "You may use `dict.items()`"? I mean, it's exactly my answer with one small improvement unrelated to the question, and it doesn't work to well for Python 2.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen I think mine would be better than yours in terms of performance.

Answer (score 1):

A way you can do this is by splitting the string into words and whitespace, then searching for any item that begins with `(`. After this, simply replace the item in the list and re-concatenate the list into a string. For example.

```
word_dict = {'market': 'library', 'fruit': 'books', 'school': 'class', 'algebra': 'calculus'};
string1 = "Today I went to the (market) to pick up some (fruit)."
string_list = string1.split()
for item in string_list:
    if item[0] == '(':
        i = string_list.index(item)
        new_string = item[1:-1]
        string_list[i] == word_dict[new_string]
print ' '.join(word[0] for word in string_list)
```

Best of luck and happy coding!