# What characters are valid in dictionary keys?

Tags: python

I thought I would find my answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42514939/what-are-valid-keys-according-to-python-str-format-documentation/42598751#42598751), but it did not really list what the valid characters are. I have attempted to use a string variable as a key, but received a key error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./validate.py", line 18, in <module>
    mylist = read_from_files(mydir)
  File "/home/username/utils.py", line 190, in function_name
    mydict[jobname]['jobname'] = jobname   <--- This is the offending line
KeyError: 'APPLEND.ABCDEF123_'
```

I assumed that the period or the underscore is the problem, but since this is a string, shouldn't it not matter what the string value is?

What are the valid characters that you can use in a dictionary key? (Or am I way off base and it's breaking for another reason?)

I have a relatively complex data structure, a list of dictionaries which contain lists of dictionaries, but up until now I've not had any problems, but I also hadn't attempted to use a variable for my dict key.

Even [this link from devleoper.com](https://www.developer.com/lang/other/article.php/630831/learn-to-program-using-python-valid-keys-key-lists-iteration.htm) reiterates that you can use any immutable object as a key. A string is immutable...

Source code: (from read_from_files function)

```
with open(file, "r") as fhFile:
    mydict['rawcode'] = fhFile.read()
    # cleaning up the - separators
    mydict['rawcode'] = mydict['rawcode'].replace('-\n','')   # This works just fine
    mydict['linelist'] = mydict['rawcode'].split("\n")        # This works just fine
    mydict['joblist'] = []
    newJob = False
    for eachline in mydict['linelist']:
        print(str(eachline))
        # Identify job names
        if "_JOB" in eachline:
            newJob = True  # We're in the same job until newJob = False, then start over
            jobname = eachline.split()[1].split("%")[0]   # This part also works just fine
            mydict['joblist'].append(jobname)             # Also works just fine
            mydict[jobname]['jobname'] = jobname          # Throwing KeyError
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: all `str` objects are valid keys, the problem is your key doesn't exist in the dictionary, so you are getting a `KeyError`

Comment: I thought you could create a new key with an assignment statement assuming the dictionary already existed?  `mydict['newkey'] = 'somevalue'`? Is not not the case?

Comment: Yes that is the case. That is not what you are doing. `mydict[x][y] = z` is equivalent to `temp = mydict[x]; temp[y] = z`. it is failing at `temp = mydict[x]`

Comment: Ah, I see. I guess I thought that since mydict was already created, I could use it without caution, even creating a dictionary of dictionaries...  I'll have to rethink the design I guess... thank you!

Comment: quick fix: `mydict.setdefault(jobname, {})['jobname'] = jobname` or use a `collections.defaultdict`

Comment: Wonderful -- that's exactly what I needed -- thanks so much! (Little surprised by the close vote already, thought it was a well-asked question...)  If the question doesn't get closed, if you make that comment an answer I'd be glad to accept it.

Comment: I'm on my phone, go ahead and answer/accept it yourself!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the line `mydict[jobname]['jobname'] = jobname`, the dict `mydict[jobname]` is not yet defined, so you have to define it first:

```
mydict[jobname] = {}
mydict[jobname]['jobname'] = jobname
```

Comment: This did the trick, and is more straightforward than the setdefault answer I admit -- thank you!