# Python dictionary key formatting for print does not work for numerical strings

Tags: python, dictionary, printing

I learned from [Python anti-patterns](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/readability/not_using_dict_keys_when_formatting_strings.html) that you could do this:

```
person = {
    'first': 'Tobin',
    'age':20
}

print('{first} is {age} years old'.format(**person))
# Output: Tobin is 20 years old

person = {
    'first':'Tobin',
    'last': 'Brown',
    'age':20
}
print('{first} {last} is {age} years old'.format(**person))
# Output: Tobin Brown is 20 years old
```

However, when my dictionary contains numerical keys, it does not work:

```
>>> d = {'123': 123}
>>> d
{'123': 123}
>>> print('{123} is 123 value'.format(**d))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

This applies to both Python 2 and 3. 
Is this a known limitation?

Comment: I would recommend you to check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11130837/6699447)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider that there are, broadly speaking, three ways to indicate that some external expression should be inserted into a string whose `format` method is called:

1. Implicitly, by position

`'{}, {}, {}'.format('huey', 'dewey', 'louie')` gives `'huey, dewey, louie'`.

2. Explicitly, by position

`'{2}, {1}, {0}'.format('huey', 'dewey', 'louie')` gives `'louie, dewey, huey'`.

3. Explicitly, by name

`'{first}, {second}, {third}'.format(first='huey', second='dewey', third='louie')` gives `'huey, dewey, louie'`.

Recall that in Python, keyword arguments and variable names cannot start with a number.

This limitation is relevant to our current situation: if such keyword arguments were possible, we would not be able to resolve the *ambiguity* between cases 2 and 3; should `{0}` refer to the first element of the unnamed additional arguments, or the keyword argument `0`?

Since non-string keyword arguments are *not* possible, there is no ambiguity, and an integer within braces always means the second case. Therefore, in your code, `{123}` in fact refers to the 124th element of the argument-`tuple` passed to `format`, and of course there is no such element.

For completeness, let's look at f-strings, introduced in Python 3.6:

```
insert_me = 'cake'
print(f'{insert_me}')
```

Output:

```
cake
```

We can't do this:

```
123 = 'cake'  # illegal variable definition
print(f'{123}')
```

Therefore, Python interprets `123` in the braces as an *integer literal*, and prints `'123'`.

Comment: This makes perfect sense! print() looks for the tuple of positional variables only to find that it reaches the end and impossible to retrieve vars[123].

Comment: @kakyo I realised I got so caught up in explaining the reason that I forgot to address your specific question. Yes, that is precisely it.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply it as following

```
   print('{} is 123 value'.format(*d))
```

It can work for both Python2 and Python3 as well